# proof by way of contradiction-trig style

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Ok here we go:
if x belongs to the interval [0,pi/2], prove sin(x)+cos(x)>=1. 
I have come up with this:
By way of contradiction, if x belongs to the interval [0,pi/2], then sin(x)+cos(x) is not >=1.
Assume x is in the interval [0,pi/2].
Let x=0. Then we observe:
sin(0)+cos(0) not >= 1.
=0+1 not >=1 which is a contradiction.
My question is this: this seems like it's just a counterexample and not really a proof by contradiction because wouldn't this have to have every possible case within the interval (which is pretty impractical) to make it work?  Ultimately, would would need to happen to make it "air tight?"

Comment: $1\geq 1$ is a true statement.

Comment: Alternative answer: what is sin(x+pi/4)?

Comment: i couldn't figure out how to make it have a line through that so it would say "1 is not greater than or equal to 1" ...which is false.

Comment: Geometrically, $\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)\geq 1$ says that the points on the unit circle lie either on or above the line $x+y=1$ when $x,y\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Both $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are continuous and concave functions on $I=\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. It follows that the endpoints of $I$ are points of minimum for $\sin(x)+\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you doubt the validaty of your proof.
When that happens to me- i try to use the same logical steps in order prove  something that i know is **false**.
I would suggest you try to expand the result to the closed set $[0,\pi]$. 
Obviously, the same logic would lead you to the conclusion that this is also true for the above set.

The reason it is not a valid proof is because you only showed the contradication for a specific number: 0.
In a way, what you tried to do is prove a property of a set by showing it is true for just 1 member of that set.

Comment: exactly.  wish i could input symbols here so... my apologies.  but I know for contradiction, we need "P and not P."  So if P is the interval part, somehow that whole interval would need to contradict against the sin(x)+cos(x) is not greater than or equal to 1.